# Getting "Parsing error: 'return' outside of function"

Tags: eslint

I am trying to lint and I am getting...

```
 Parsing error: 'return' outside of function
```

This is in a markdown document so it should be ignored. How do I explicitly ignore this rule?

Comment: Rather than ignore it, maybe we can see the code to find out why it's yielding that error in the first place? It's an important rule. But since this is a markdown document, there's really no reason to lint it. Sounds like you have the word "return" as plain text, and that triggers it.

Comment: Why are you linting a markdown document?

Comment: @JJJ not me it is a fork

Comment: @Alec I get that I am ignoring it only for Markdown docs.